# T/F : If $a_{n} \geq 0$, $p > 1$ and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n}$ converges, then $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(a_{n})^{p}$ converges

Tags: calculus

T/F : If $a_{n} \geq 0$, $p > 1$ and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n}$ converges, then $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(a_{n})^{p}$ converges

In every example I'm trying to make it ends up being true, but I have a feeling that it is false. I need some directions/hints

Answer (score 1):

Here is a hint: if each $a_n \le 1$, then $a_n^p \le a_n$ for all $n$.

Comment: Great! I know how to solve now. Can you show me a clever way to prove that every positive fraction is greater or equal the same fraction with a higher exponent?

Comment: Just to be sure - I'm going to prove that it is true, right?

Comment: If $0 < a \le 1$ and $p > 0$ then $0 < a^p \le 1$. Thus if $0 <a \le 1$ and $p > 1$ then $0 < a^{p-1} \le 1$. Now multiply by $a$.